# anonymous function passed from PHP and set specific `this` reference

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, this

I have a PHP class with a static function:

```
<? echo view::getUserSelector() ?>
```

Which outputs:

```
<div id="user_selector">
    <div class="user">
        <h1>Username1</h1>
        <a href="javascript:selectUser(this);">select</a>
    </div>
    <div class="user">
        <h1>Username2</h1>
        <a href="javascript:selectUser(this);">select</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**What do I need to do to make this possible?:**

```
<? echo view::getUserSelector(array('onSelect' => 'function() { alert(this.id); }')); ?>
```

1. How do I 'add' the `onSelect`-value as a function of `div#user_selector`?
2. How do I 'call' `div#user_selector.onSelect()` with `this` reference as `div#user_select`?

Javascript:

```
function selectUser(anchor) {
    //remove all 'selected' classes from $user_selector child divs
    //add 'selected' class to parent div.user of anchor
}
```

Comment: You have conflicting requirements: "I want this code to execute after selectUser() has executed. ... And how do I execute this function in the selectUser() function?" You can't simultaneously execute it *in* selectUser() *and* after selectUser(). Can you clarify what you're looking for?

Comment: You're right, I rephrased the issue. Thanx

Comment: since you can't normally "select" a div, what do you envision the user doing in order to "select" it?

Comment: That doesn't really matter for what I'm trying to achieve right? But I add a class 'selected' (css) to the parent-div of the anchor which invokes the selectUser() function, after I removed the 'selected' from previously selected divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP function, where you output all this, you could add this inside script tags, which gives you what you want (from what I can understand).

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var uSelect = document.getElementById('user_select');
uSelect.onSelect = function() {
    alert(this.id);
}

function selectUser(anchor) {
    //remove all 'selected' classes from $user_selector child divs
    //add 'selected' class to parent div.user of anchor
    uSelect.onSelect();
}
</script>
```

But, one more resource I want to point out, is if you want to simply declare the function and are curious how to assign any given object to be 'this' inside it, Javascript functions have to methods `call` and `apply`.

For example: you could try something like this as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript>
var onSelect = function() {
    alert(this.id);
}

function selectUser(anchor) {
    //remove all 'selected' classes from $user_selector child divs
    //add 'selected' class to parent div.user of anchor
    var node = anchor;
    while(node && node.parentNode) {
        if(node.getAttribute('id') == 'user_select') {
            //apply(thisRef, argsArray)
            //call(thisRef, arg1, arg2 [...])

            onSelect.apply(node);
            break;
        }
        node = node.parentNode;
    }
}
</script>
```